# How to type check a pytorch loss?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to type check the fact that a given argument is a default torch loss (criterion) and optimize in python so I'm sure that I can compute the following operations :

```py
loss = criterion(y_pred, y_batch)
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Ultimatly, I just want to check that something like :

```py
assert isinstance(criterion, torch.loss)
assert isinstance(optimizer, torch.optimizer)
```

But I can't find a way of doing that in torch documentation.

Any idea ?

Comment: After some further readings, all pre defined torch losses inherits from torch.nn.modules.loss._Loss which could be a start no ?

Comment: Agree with your point. I mis-understood your question. Deleted my comment for the same. @Louis

Answer (score 0):

The losses come from `torch.nn.modules.loss` which is not a class. But we could check if the "path" of a loss contains it, for example like this:

```py
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

def is_torch_loss(criterion) -> bool:
    type_ = str(type(criterion)).split("'")[1]
    parent = type_.rsplit(".", 1)[0]
    
    return parent == "torch.nn.modules.loss"


is_loss = is_torch_loss(criterion)
```

Comment: all torch losses inherits from : `torch.nn.modules.loss._Loss` 
all torch optimize are of the instance : `torch.optim.Optimizer`

Answer (score 0):

You can access nn

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

if isinstance(criterion, nn.modules.loss._Loss):
    print("The criterion is a PyTorch loss function.")
else:
    print("The criterion is not a PyTorch loss function.")
```

```
>>> criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
>>> isinstance(criterion, nn.modules.loss._Loss)
True
```